# How to clear the cv::Mat contents?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` but I have already inserted it with some values, how do I clear the contents in it?

Answer (score 25):

If you want to release the memory of the `Mat` variable use `release()`.

```
Mat m;
// initialize m or do some processing
m.release();
```

For a vector of `cv::Mat` objects you can release the memory of the whole vector with `myvector.clear()`.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> myvector;
// initialize myvector .. 

myvector.clear(); // to release the memory of the vector
```

Comment: If you use m.release() and try to use the Mat again, you gonna get an error. Since it seems he just one to reset the values, assigning a Scalar value sounds much better approach.

Comment: @luiz_s81 it's not clear what he wants; it's up to the user. What's the point of setting Mat elements to zero anyway? it's an extra operation that  doesn't make the matrix take any less memory. In case he wants to reuse the matrix he might as well just keep the previous matrix and then re-assign its elements to whatever he wants (not necessarily to zeros) when needed.

Answer (score 14):

From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html):

```
// sets all or some matrix elements to s
Mat& operator = (const Scalar& s);
```

then we could do

```
m = Scalar(0,0,0);
```

to fill with black pixels. Scalar has 4 components, the last - alpha - is optional.

Answer (score 9):

You should call release() function.

```
 Mat img = Mat(Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
 img.release();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `release` the current contents or assign a new `Mat`.

```
Mat m = Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_8U);

cout << "m: " << m << endl;
m.release();  //this will remove Mat m from memory

//Another way to clear the contents is by assigning an empty Mat:
m = Mat();

//After this the Mat can be re-assigned another value for example:
m = Mat::zeros(2,3, CV_8U);
cout << "m: " << m << endl;
```

Comment: m.release() will remove the memory of the Mat variable. But by just assigning m to Mat() will clear the contents and it was not meant to do in continuation with m.release(). After m being assigned Mat(), it can be re-assigned to some other values say Mat::zeros(2,3, CV_8U)

Answer (score 0):

You could always *redeclare* it if you want to empty the mat but keep using the variable. Idk if that's what you want but since the other answer to "clearing" a mat is .release() I'd just go to mention this.

Edit: My bad. I didn't realise how unclear my answer was. I was just answering the question of "how to clear a Mat variable of it's contents". Another person had answered that one can just do .release() to the variable, like for example, the person has a variable like
`cv::Mat testMat;` and later on it's declared (as the question implied).
One person said that you could do a simple `testMat.release()`. And if that's what op wants then there you go. But in the off chance that op just wants to clear the declaration of the variable, i just thought to mention that he/she could just re-declare it, like do a simple `testMat = *some new information*` later on. Also, i mixed up define and declare. My bad

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.